# How many operations does this simple for loop have?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious, how many operations does the following code have? This has nothing to do with premature optimization, that is the devil. I am to get in to very serious recursive operations later and want to know how it works on a smaller scale. For my personal interest only.

E.g.

```
var i, max, fruits = ["apple","banana","orange","mango"]; 
for (i = 0, max = fruits.length;i < max; i+=1) {
   // do something with fruits[i]
}
```

- I'm guessing, line one: 1 operation (assign fruits)
- Second line, first iteration: 5 operations (assign i, length lookup, assign max, compare, increase i)
- Second line, second iteration: 2 operations (compare, increase i)
- Second line, third iteration: 2 operations (compare, increase i)
- Second line, fourth iteration: 2 operations

I am aware that these operations vary in cost of time and memory, **are there any rule of thumbs to go by?**

Comment: Rule of thumb: Don't worry about it. Focus on what is the most understandable for your future self to read. Only worry about optimization when you can prove that it is slowing things down.

Comment: Unless you're nesting loops, there's rarely a reason to worry about their performance impact.

Comment: I agree with both above. You shouldn't worry about how many operations are being performed, especially at such a small scale. What you want to be careful of however is the general complexity and efficiency of your code, i.e. are you using nested loops when they can be avoided entirely?

Comment: On the same page, you could read [this article](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: @DBS I will be getting into recursive nad nesting soon enough, hence I want a simple example to understand first.

Comment: @Aaron I never carry out premature optimization, ever. I am just curious.

Comment: The amount of JavaScript "operations" says very little about actual performance. Does `i+=1` count as 1 operation ("increase `i`") or 3 ("read `i`", "add 1 to value", "write new value to `i`")? Do "create array of 10 elements" and "create array of 1000000 elements" both count as 1 operation? In the end, 99% of your code is not performance critical, and for the 1% that does matter you should measure *real* performance characteristics: execution time, CPU load, memory usage,...

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Which operations are worth counting then. As this is applied in cs quite often with big o. You tell me.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens  I do benchmark when deciding, but what does the community think about which operations to include? There are different ways of writing algorithms and hence counting time complexity.

Comment: "about which operations to include?" --- whatever needs to be used to: 1) solve the problem 2) be readable.

Comment: "Which operations are worth counting then" --- none of them. Unless you're a browser/JS engine engineer.

Comment: @KarlMorrison Big O analysis is part of complexity theory, which is about *algorithms* - not about *code*. The programming language doesn't matter, often you just write the algorithms as pseudo-code. The operations that you should be counting depends *heavily* on the algorithm(s) you're analyzing: for example "amount of comparisons" or "amount of swaps" is common for sorting algorithms, "amount of visited nodes" is common for graph search problems. Still, the analysis is based on a *cost model*, which is very different from the *actual cost* of running code on an actual computer.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: I think this is a good question -- not sure why it got downvoted since there don't seem to be many questions like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bite, lets break it down.  Note that an "operation" is not a CPU operation, we're talking about JavaScript here, about as far away from the CPU as you can get.

**`var i, max, fruits ...`** 3 variable declarations, provisioning an area of memory for each variable.

**= `fru["apple","banana","orange","mango"];`**  1 new Array() initialization with 4 string literal assignments as well, so that's 5, plus the assignment so that's 6.

**`i = 0,`** 1 assignment, i was already declared.

**`max = fruits.length`** 1 assignment, 1 dictionary lookup for length (? operations),

**`i < max`** 1 conditional.... but the condition is evaluated on every loop iteration.  Now I think v8 will optimise this but I can't be sure.

**`i+=1`** same as i++ here, this should really count as 1, maybe 2, depending on the compiler.

That gives us 14 or 15 operations, approximately, depending on the compiler.  For optimization here there's nothing much to be done.  My rule of thumb here is that the more expensive operations will be related to the strings, what might you do with them?